# Changing dataset connection string in web config at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I have a *c#* generated dataset.

How can I change the connection string so I can use the dataset with another (identically structured yet differently populated) database?

This has to occur at runtime as I do not know the server or database name at compile time. I am using **c# 3.5**.

Comment: A strongly typed DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no simple way and you cannot change the Connection-String programmatically for the entire `DataSet` since it's defined for every `TableAdapter`.

You need to create the partial class of the `TableAdapter` to  change the connection-string since the `Connection` property is `internal` (if your DAL is in a different assembly). Don't change the `designer.cs` file since it will be recreated automatically after the next change on the designer. To create it just right-click the DataSet and chose "show code".

For example (assuming the `TableAdapter` is named `ProductTableAdapter`):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters
{
    public partial class ProductTableAdapter 
    {
        public string ConnectionString {
            get { return Connection.ConnectionString; }
            set { Connection.ConnectionString = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can change it easily:

```
var productTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductTableAdapter();
productTableAdapter.ConnectionString = someOtherConnectionString;
```

Here's a screenshot of my sample `DataSet` and the created file `DataSet1.cs`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ide mvs 2008
in your **settings.designer.cs** verifier or edit this

```
  public string NamOfappConnectionString{
        get {
            return ((string)(this["NamOfappConnectionString"]));
        }
      //add this line     
        set {
            this["NamOfappConnectionString"]=value;
        }
    }

 //atr untime use this


string myconnexion = "Data Source=" + txt_data_source.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + txt_initial_catalog.Text + ";Persist Security Info=True;";

    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("NamOfappConnectionString", myconnexion);
```

//save into setting

```
Properties.Settings.Default.NamOfappConnectionString= myconnexion;
Application.Restart();
```